# How to format USB flash drive to work with older device?

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I have 2 usb stics. One of them (64MB) is working fine with Nikon npl632. However this device seems not to support any modern flash drives. What I'am willing to do is to format new usb stick - much larger and shrink it to become compatible. I am enclosing Minitool partition wizzard screenshot with my progress made so far. I can't make it work, what am I missing?
[image: MINITOOL partition wizzard]

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: It is windows7 x64